# list append not working correctly

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, append

I have code that is supposed to fill in IP address ranges so that none overlap. I have had a previous version of this that works great but I changed it automate all the passes and be less wasteful and resource intensive.

This is my current code:

```
import ipaddress
import csv
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter
import cProfile
import pstats
import operator
import time

start_time=time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p", time.localtime())


alphlst=[]
SubnetDic1=[]
global SubnetDic2

with open(r'C:\ExampleBefore.csv', newline='') as fin:

    read = DictReader(fin)

    for line in read:
        alphlst.append(line)



def program():
    print("started")
    global alphlst
    lst3=[]
    global lst4
    lst4=[]
    global lst5
    lst5=[]
    endlist=[]
    global SubnetDic1
    SubnetDic1=[]
    global SubnetDic2
    SubnetDic2=[]
    global SubOut1
    SubOut1=[]
    global SubOut2
    SubOut2=[]
    msklst=[]
    global lst
    lst=[]

    print(alphlst)

    print("^ alphlst")


    for li in alphlst:
        li['CIDR']=ipaddress.ip_network(li['CIDR'])
        SubnetDic2.append(li)
        if str(li['CIDR'].netmask) != '255.255.255.255':
            SubnetDic1.append(li)

    print("alph list clear")


    alphlst=[]

    print("after alph list clear")


    print("Dic lists completed")

    def Overlap(y, z):

        global lst5
        global lst

        try:
            if y['CIDR'].overlaps(z['CIDR']):
                lst=list(y['CIDR'].address_exclude(z['CIDR'])) # List of subnets excluding line4 subnet
                if len(lst) != 0:
                    print("not empty. {} is obsolete.".format(y['CIDR']))
                    lst5.append(str(y['CIDR']))
                    print(lst)
        except ValueError:
            return False





    for line3 in SubnetDic1:
        line3['CIDR']=ipaddress.ip_network(line3['CIDR']) # Convert IP ranges to ip network object
        lst3.append(str(line3['CIDR']))
        for line4 in SubnetDic2:
            line4['CIDR']=ipaddress.ip_network(line4['CIDR']) # Convert IP ranges to ip network object
            Overlap(line3, line4) # Tests for IP overlap
            for val in lst:
                if str(val) not in lst3:
                    if str(val) not in lst4:
                        subwr=line3
                        subwr['CIDR']=val # New range
                        subwr['IPStart']=val.network_address #New net address
                        subwr['IPStop']=val.broadcast_address #New broadcast address
                        SubOut1.append(subwr)
                        print("{} is line3".format(subwr))
                        print("{} is line3 tst".format(line3))
                        lst4.append(str(val))



    print(SubOut1)
    print("^ SubOut1")




    print("Subnet part1 completed")

    global lst7


    lst7=[]


    for line5 in SubnetDic2:
        line5['CIDR']=ipaddress.ip_network(line5['CIDR']) # Convert IP ranges to ip network object
        lst7.append(str(line5['CIDR']))
        print("{} line5 end".format(line5))
        if str(line5['CIDR']) not in lst5:
            print("{} line5 aft".format(line5))
            SubOut2.append(line5) # Write lines

    print("Subnet part2 completed")


    for line6 in SubOut2:
        endlist.append(line6)

    print("Subnet part3 completed")

    for line7 in SubOut1:
        endlist.append(line7)

    print("Subnet part4 completed")

    lst8=[]

    for line10 in endlist:
        line10['CIDR']=ipaddress.ip_network(line10['CIDR'])
        line10['Mask']=line10['CIDR'].netmask
        print("{} is line10 try".format(line10))
        if str(line10['CIDR']) not in lst8:
            msklst.append(line10)
            lst8.append(str(line10['CIDR']))
            print("{} is line10 append".format(line10))



    srtlst=sorted(msklst, key=operator.itemgetter('Mask'), reverse=True)

    for lip in srtlst:
        alphlst.append(lip)






def all_true(items):
    return all(x == "True" for x in items)

lstadd=[]

def in_lst():

    global lst4
    global SubnetDic2
    global lstadd
    global lst7

    lstadd=[]

    for l in lst4:
        if l in lst7:
            lstadd.append("True")
        else:
            lstadd.append("False")

    print(lstadd)
    print(lst4)

def chk_lst():

    print("running chk_lst")

    in_lst()

    global lstadd

    if all_true(lstadd):
        return True
    else:
        return False


pass_start=time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p", time.localtime())
cnt=1
cProfile.run('program()', 'prostats')
pass_end=time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p", time.localtime())
p = pstats.Stats('prostats')
p.print_stats(0)
print("Pass {0}. Start: {1} End: {2}".format(cnt, pass_start, pass_end))


while chk_lst() is False:
    pass_start2=time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p", time.localtime())
    cnt = cnt + 1
    cProfile.run('program()', 'prostats2')
    pass_end2=time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p", time.localtime())
    p = pstats.Stats('prostats2')
    p.print_stats(0)
    print("Pass {0}. Start: {1} End: {2}".format(cnt, pass_start2, pass_end2))


print("All Subnets Done")    


with open(r'C:\ExampleBefore.csv', newline='') as fin7,\
     open(r'C:\TstExample-sort1.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout5:

        read7 = DictReader(fin7)

        writenum6 = DictWriter(fout5, fieldnames=read7.fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore') 
        writenum6.writeheader()

        global alphlst

        for lime in alphlst:
           writenum6.writerow(lime)

        print("Write Complete")
```

I know it's messy and I know I am doing some unnecessary things in it right now, that is because I was trying things to make it work and haven't cleaned it up yet. All the printing, for example is for troubleshooting only.

This is and example of the input file (the real one is much bigger though):

```
Zone Name,IPStart,IPStop,CIDR,Source
Group A - Server,10.55.22.1/32,10.55.22.1/32,10.55.22.1/32,New List
Group A Sales Primary routers,10.23.1.0,10.23.1.15,10.24.1.0/28,New List
Group A Sales Web Servers - Primary,10.18.0.0,10.18.0.255,10.18.0.0/24,New List
Group A Marketing,10.62.0.0,10.62.255.255,10.62.0.0/16,New List
Group A Research,10.62.0.0,10.63.255.255,10.62.0.0/15,Old List
Group A Sales Web Servers,10.16.0.0,10.19.255.255,10.16.0.0/14,New List
Group A Sales,10.16.0.0,10.31.255.255,10.16.0.0/12,New List
Group A,10.0.0.0,10.127.255.255,10.0.0.0/9,New List
Group B,10.128.0.0,10.255.255.255,10.128.0.0/9,Old List
```

I have figured out that the problem is in this part of the code:

```
for line3 in SubnetDic1:
        line3['CIDR']=ipaddress.ip_network(line3['CIDR']) # Convert IP ranges to ip network object
        lst3.append(str(line3['CIDR']))
        for line4 in SubnetDic2:
            line4['CIDR']=ipaddress.ip_network(line4['CIDR']) # Convert IP ranges to ip network object
            Overlap(line3, line4) # Tests for IP overlap
            for val in lst:
                if str(val) not in lst3:
                    if str(val) not in lst4:
                        subwr=line3
                        subwr['CIDR']=val # New range
                        subwr['IPStart']=val.network_address #New net address
                        subwr['IPStop']=val.broadcast_address #New broadcast address
                        SubOut1.append(subwr)
                        print("{} is line3".format(subwr))
                        print("{} is line3 tst".format(line3))
                        lst4.append(str(val))



    print(SubOut1)
    print("^ SubOut1")
```

Basically, the value being appended to `SubOut1` does not match what is supposed to be. It is however printing what it is supposed to be in both of the lines `print("{} is line3".format(subwr))` and `print("{} is line3 tst".format(line3))`. Keep in mind I was using "line3" before as the value to append to the list instead of `subwr` but that produced the same result.

This is an example of what it prints for the lines `print("{} is line3".format(subwr))` and `print("{} is line3 tst".format(line3))`:

```
{'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.64.0.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.64.0.0/10'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.127.255.255')} is line3
{'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.64.0.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.64.0.0/10'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.127.255.255')} is line3 tst
```

And this is what is in the list "SubOut1" the first pass (when it SHOULD have the line above in it and others):

```
[{'Zone Name': 'Group A Research', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.63.0.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.63.0.0/16'), 'Source': 'Old List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.63.255.255')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales Web Servers', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.18.1.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.18.1.0/24'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.18.1.255')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales Web Servers', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.18.1.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.18.1.0/24'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.18.1.255')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales Web Servers', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.18.1.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.18.1.0/24'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.18.1.255')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales Web Servers', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.18.1.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.18.1.0/24'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.18.1.255')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales Web Servers', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.18.1.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.18.1.0/24'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.18.1.255')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales Web Servers', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.18.1.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.18.1.0/24'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.18.1.255')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales Web Servers', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.18.1.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.18.1.0/24'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.18.1.255')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales Web Servers', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.18.1.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.18.1.0/24'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.18.1.255')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales Web Servers', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.18.1.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.18.1.0/24'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.18.1.255')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales Web Servers', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.18.1.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.18.1.0/24'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.18.1.255')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A Sales', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.24.1.16'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.24.1.16/28'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.24.1.31')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}, {'Zone Name': 'Group A', 'IPStart': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0'), 'CIDR': IPv4Network('10.55.22.0/32'), 'Source': 'New List', 'IPStop': IPv4Address('10.55.22.0')}]
```

The code that worked before used the DictWriter to write row instead of appending to a list. It was "write.writerow(line3)" instead of what it is now `SubOut1.append(subwr)` or the same thing: `SubOut1.append(line3)`.

Can someone please help me figure out why it is not appending the correct values to `SubOut1` and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: This is a lot of code to read through - you might have more luck if you pare it down a bit and try to be more concise with what you think the problem is (opposite issue to the usual "please provide context for this problem").

Comment: Can you produce a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)? This is a lot of code to wade through. "By identifying more clearly where the problem occurs, you have just made an important step toward solving it. The process that highlights where a problem *originates* can, in itself, help you to solve it. You might look more closely at the part you cut out, and in doing so, spot the problem."

Comment: Okay, I will try to do that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR.

That said, This line looks really suspicious:

```
subwr=line3
```

I think it shouldl be:

```
subwr=line3.copy()
```

The problem is that in Python objects are always references, so if you do the following:

```
SubOut1 = []
line3 = {}

line3[0] = "usefuldata"
subwr = line3
SubOut1.append(subwr)

line3[0] = "uselessdata"

print SubOut1
```

And you'll get `{0:"useless data"}`. because all `subwr`, `line3` and `SubOut1[0]` are references to the very same object. If you modify this object you'll be able to see that change everywhere.

Replace the assignment with `subwr = line3.copy()` and you'll get the expected results.

Partial off-topic note: that's the same reason why you should not do this to initialize your lists:

```
a = b = c = []
```

But you have to do this instead:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
```